# Retrieving attribute values depending on the value of another attribute using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml doc:

```
<database>

<order>
    <data>
        <field name="time" value="10:10:10" />
    </data>
    <data>
        <field name="product" value="product_type_1">
            <field name="attributeA" value="Foo" />
            <field name="attributeB" value="Bar" />
        </field>
        <field name="attributeC" value="Jeam" />
        <field name="attributeD" value="Beam" />
        <field name="attributeE" value="Deam" />
    </data>
</order>

<order>
    <data>
        <field name="time" value="10:10:11" />
    </data>
    <data>
        <field name="product" value="product_type_2">
            <field name="attributeF" value="Bravo" />
            <field name="attributeG" value="Echo" />
        </field>
        <field name="attributeC" value="Jeam2" />
        <field name="attributeD" value="Beam2" />
        <field name="attributeJ" value="Charlie" />
        <field name="attributeK" value="Tango" />
        <field name="attributeL" value="Zulu" />
    </data>
</order>
```

It is a set of "order" elements but the "field" (both on quantity and type) depend on the value of the element whose name is "product". I am interested in extracting info depending on the value of the product. More specifically, I would end up with something like this table:

```
Time      Product          AttributeA AttributeB AttributeC AttributeD
10:10:10  product_type_1   Foo        Bar        Jeam       Beam
10:10:11  product_type_2                         Jeam2      Beam2
```

In other words I am trying to "cut" unesessary info depending on the value of child element of "order". I am trying to achive this by using xpath (in java) but I am stuck. It is impossible for me to emulate the "if" condition described above.

I am thinking of using and xpath query to retrieve one order element at a time, then query for the product type and then choose the apropriate xpath to retieve the coresponding attributes, but that sounds really inneficient and slow.

Is it possible to do it more efficiently? Is xpath not the right answer here?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: The alignment and organization of the data you see above doesn't really matter as long as I retrieve the correct data then I am sure I'll be able to print them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use XPath, you will need at least XPath 3.0 or XQuery (this code is valid in both of them). Have a look at XQuery engines if you want to use this in Java, for example Saxon, BaseX, eXist DB, ...

```
for $order in /database/order
return string-join((
  $order//field[@name='time']/@value,
  $order//field[@name='product']/@value,
  ($order//field[@name='attributeA']/@value, '')[1],
  ($order//field[@name='attributeB']/@value, '')[1],
  ($order//field[@name='attributeC']/@value, '')[1],
  ($order//field[@name='attributeD']/@value, '')[1]),
  '&#9;')
```

The pattern used for the attributes makes sure that empty values do not break the table layout (so for the second product type, attributes C and D do not get attributes A and B). `&#9;` is the tab character.

---

If you want to use Java for further processing the output, I'd go with this: Fetch all orders  (`/database/order`) and loop over them. Then, for each order, use DOM (or XPath again) to fetch the nodes you need. Yet it seems that the question you asked is not your actual problem, it might be that using XQuery could lead to a cleaner solution.

Comment: Due to my limited knowledge of XPath I was given the impression that XPath would work as a magic wand for my problem. It is soon became apparent that XPath alone is not the answer. XQuery may have a learning curve so I focusing XPath with DOM like Jens Erat suggested. I am having trouble dealing with medium-big (~1gb) size xml files in matters of memory, with that way but I investigating and I try to post a solution here.

Comment: You might want to look at XML databases like BaseX, Sedna and eXist -- you should not have problems with main memory then. XQuery definitely has a steep learning curve if you are not used to functional programming, but is worth the effort. BaseX has some nice visualization tools which can help you while learning XQuery and is rather easy to set up. _(Disclaimer: I'm somewhat affiliated with the BaseX team.)_